# ObjectListView minimumWidth on columns doesn't appear to work in Windows

Tags: python, windows-8, wxpython

Here is my column definition:

```
self.results_list.SetColumns([
    ColumnDefn('Street name', 'left', valueGetter='streetname',
               minimumWidth=150),
    ColumnDefn('House number', 'left', valueGetter='housenumber',
               minimumWidth=100),
    ColumnDefn('Letter', 'left', valueGetter='letter',
               minimumWidth=75),
    ColumnDefn('Postal code', 'right', valueGetter='postalcode',
               minimumWidth=120),
    ColumnDefn('City', 'left', valueGetter='city', minimumWidth=100,
               isSpaceFilling=True),
])
```

On OSX it looks great:

[image: OSX]

But on Windows...

[image: Windows]

How can I get the minimumWidth to apply even though there's no data in the ObjectListView?

---

*I'm using Windows 8 and wxPython 2.9*

Comment: That has always worked for me on Windows 7 and below. I'd ask on the wxPython user's group though. Maybe someone on there has Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

For the third option in the ColumnDefn I added a -1 and the columns were adjusted to the minimum width that you specified when there is no data in the ObjectListView on Windows.

```
self.results_list.SetColumns([
ColumnDefn('Street name', 'left', -1, valueGetter='streetname',
           minimumWidth=150),
ColumnDefn('House number', 'left', -1, valueGetter='housenumber',
           minimumWidth=100),
ColumnDefn('Letter', 'left', -1, valueGetter='letter',
           minimumWidth=75),
ColumnDefn('Postal code', 'right', -1, valueGetter='postalcode',
           minimumWidth=120),
ColumnDefn('City', 'left', -1, valueGetter='city', minimumWidth=100,
           isSpaceFilling=True),])
```

Comment: That had absolutely no effect. Which version of Windows are you using? (I'm on Windows 8 with wxPython 2.9)

Comment: I am using Windows 7 with wxPython 2.8